# How to prepare for algebraic topology exam

Tags: algebraic-topology, self-learning, advice, learning

I have 2 weeks of studying for my algebraic topology exam (based mostly on Hatcher's book - including homotopy, fundamental group, covering spaces and homology).

Problem is, my lecturer was extremely disorgenized. Going through the material is going to be excruciating, even though I've writen everything myself. It's a total of 26 lectures with about 5-6 pages per lecture.

What helps me, most of the time, is to sumerize the lectures whilst solving again the homework given during the semester, leaving enough time to solve excercises from previous exams and books.

However, for this course, I'm afraid summarizing would take too long due to the messy material. Has it been well orgenized, summarizing would have been my choice.  I did find some useful, well written, summaries but I think that going through other people summaries won't have the same effect.

What should I do to cut my losses? Should I rigorously go through each proposition's proof? Should I give up summarizing? In this course, is it better to focus on excercises rather then theory?
Answers & Tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the statements and proofs of the big theorems, and know how to compute $\pi_1$ (via van Kampen or covering spaces) and homology (via Mayer-Vietoris, Künneth, etc., or just directly) of a variety of spaces. Given how disorganized it sounds, it might be too hard to know all the details of all the proofs, so try to pick results that are "big ideas" or useful tools, because they might be more likely to be on the exam (and the techniques used there might also apply to smaller results).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will take it in account. Do you think summarizing the material is a waste of a time I could use to practice exercises?

Comment: I guess it depends on how well you already know the material. If there are concepts or proof techniques you need to refresh yourself on then summarizing the material would still be a great idea,